# Extend Union Type

Tags: typescript

Consider I have these TypeScript type definitions:

```
export type Command = { AggregateId: string}

export type AddUser = (command: Command) => Promise<{streamId: string}>
export type RemoveUser = (command: Command) => Promise<{streamId: string}>

type CommandHandler = 
    | AddUser 
    | RemoveUser
```

Is there a way to have the `CommandHandler` defined in library without `AddUser` and `RemoveUser` but "attach" the to `CommandHandler` in a project which references the library containing `CommandHandler`?

Comment: What your use case for doing this? What are you trying to do with that union type, since `AddUser` and `RemoveUser` are effectively the same type?

Comment: Please see my comment to your answer. I'll update my original question accordingly.

Comment: You can use declaration merging to do this... if nobody else posts a solution by the time I get to a real machine, then I’ll do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First some terminology... there's a duality and often a confusion between certain pairs of terms in TypeScript.  The word "extend" usually refers to *narrowing* a type to make it *more* constrained.  In your case, when you say you want to "extend" the union, you don't mean it in the same sense as `extends`.  Instead, you want to *widen* the type to make it *less* constrained.  There's not a great analogous term for that in TypeScript... you'd call it `super` in something like Java.  Anyway, to be clear, you're looking to have an empty union in your library and allow other modules to add constituents into it, thereby *widening* (not extending) it.

There is a language feature called [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) which allows you to augment existing types by "re-opening" modules/namespaces/interfaces and adding properties/methods to them.  At first glance it would seem not to help, since the type you want to change is a type alias (i.e., `type X = ...`) and you can't re-open those.  And you don't want to add any property/method to it anyway.

The trick here is to make an interface like `CommandHandlerMap` whose property keys are dummy values, and whose property values are the elements of the `CommandHandler` union you're looking for.  Then you can define `type CommandHandler = CommandHandlerMap[keyof CommandHandlerMap]`.  By merging into `CommandHandlerMap` in a module, you will automatically cause the `CommandHandler` union to gain a constituent.

The code could look something like this:

**library.ts**

```
export type Command = { AggregateId: string };

export type CommandHandlerResult = { streamId: string };

export interface CommandHandlerMap {
  // will merge into this interface
}

export type CommandHandler = CommandHandlerMap[keyof CommandHandlerMap]
```

**addUser.ts**

```
import * as Library from './library';

export interface AddUserCommand extends Library.Command {
  username: string;
  somethingElse: number;
}

export type AddUser =
  (command: AddUserCommand) => Promise<Library.CommandHandlerResult>;

// reopen the CommandHandlerMap interface in the library module    
declare module './library' {
  export interface CommandHandlerMap {
    AddUser: AddUser // add this
  }
}
```

**removeUser.ts**

```
import * as Library from './library';

export interface RemoveUserCommand extends Library.Command {
  username: string;
  withExtremePrejudice: boolean;
}

export type RemoveUser =
  (command: RemoveUserCommand) => Promise<Library.CommandHandlerResult>;

// reopen the CommandHandlerMap interface in the library module
declare module './library' {
  export interface CommandHandlerMap {
    RemoveUser: RemoveUser // add this
  }
}
```

And then you can verify this works:

**index.ts**

```
import * as Library from './library';
import { RemoveUser, RemoveUserCommand } from './removeUser';

const handler: Library.CommandHandler = async (c: RemoveUserCommand) => {
  return {
    streamId: c.username
  }
}; // okay
// const handler: AddUser | RemoveUser
```

That works as far as it goes.  You can see that `Library.CommandHandler` is understood to be `AddUser | RemoveUser`.  Note that the `CommandHandlerMap` *keys* happen to be `"AddUser"` and `"RemoveUser"`, but that's not required.  We could have merged into `CommandHandlerMap` with keys `"BlahBlah"` or `"!!!@#$"`.   They are dummy keys and only need to be unique (because you don't want to collide with an existing key) for it to work.

The main caveat with this method is probably that any errors you introduce in a module might end up being flagged inside the library code instead of your module.  For example, if code in your library assumes that `CommandHandler` is definitely a function type, and someone in a module merges a non-function value into the union, you can expect the error to show up in the library.  This is a bit harder to debug.

Anyway, hope that gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://repl.it/@jcalz/AddConstituentsToUnionViaDeclarationMerging)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, this seems to work and I'll play around with it. Especially thanks for the explanation on widening vs extending. I tried another approach as well and will post some question about it later on in a new question.

Comment: Could you include an example of the *library's* code using your `CommandHandler`? Correct me if I'm wrong, but from the library's perspective, `type CommandHandler = never`, right? How will the library use it? Does it require type assertions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can't change the meaning of `CommandHandler` after the fact that way.

What you could do is have `CommandHandler` defined as:

```
export type CommandHandler = (command: Command) => Promise<{streamId: string}>
```

Then in your project, if you want `AddUser` and `RemoveUser` types, make them aliases:

```
export type AddUser = CommandHandler;
export type RemoveUser = CommandHandler;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to pass e.g. an `AddUserCommand` (which derives from `Command`) to `AddUser` while `RemoveUser`would not accept it?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler - I'm afraid I don't know. If `AddUserCommand` and `RemoveUserCommand` don't add any features, they end up being assignable to each other. That is, my first thought (next comment) doesn't work because they're assignment-compatible. Of course, if you add properties to `AddUserCommand` and different ones to `RemoveUserCommand`, that would work.

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Command%20%7B%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20AddUserCommand%20extends%20Command%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20RemoveUserCommand%20extends%20Command%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20AddUser%20%3D%20(command%3A%20AddUserCommand)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3C%7BstreamId%3Astring%7D%3E%0D%0Atype%20RemoveUser%20%3D%20(command%3A%20RemoveUserCommand)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3C%7BstreamId%3Astring%7D%3E%0D%0Alet%20addUser%3A%20AddUser%3B%0D%0Alet%20removeUserCommand%3A%20RemoveUserCommand%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0AaddUser(removeUserCommand)%3B)

Comment: But if you had `interface AddUserCommand extends Command { type: "add" }` and `interface RemoveUserCommand extends Command { type: "remove" }` they wouldn't be assignment compatible anymore.