# Can I extend types from a npm package by installing another package?

Tags: typescript

I am developping in Typescript a npm package with a core package and extension packages.
The extensions packages add some attributes to a core type in the core package.

I would like the core package to be agnostic of these additional fields. And these additional fields should be available to the end user if they import the extension packages.

Here is an exemple of the problem. Lets say I have a core package that handles parcels tracking, and extension packages for each delivery service (UPS, FedEx, USPS...)

```js
// package/shipping/index.d.ts
type ParcelTracking = {
  provider: string;
}

// package/@shipping/ups-provider/index.d.ts
declare module "shipping" {
  type ParcelTracking = ParcelTracking & {
    provider: "UPS";
    ups_tracking_number: string;
  }
}
// package/@shipping/fedex-provider/index.d.ts
declare module "shipping" {
  type ParcelTracking = ParcelTracking & {
    provider: "FEDEX";
    fedex_tracking_number: string;
    fedex_estimated_delivery_date: string;
  }
}

// my-app/index.ts
import { ParcelTracking } from "shipping";
import "@shipping/ups-provider";
import "@shipping/fedex-provider";

function updateOrderShipment(orderId: string, tracking: ParcelTracking) {
  // ... store it on the database
}

function onParcelSent(orderId: string, webhookData: any) {
  if (webhookData.caller === "UPS") {
    await updateOrderShipment(orderId, {
      provider: "UPS",
      ups_tracking_number: webhookData.tracking_number,
    });
    return;
  }

  if (webhookData.caller === "FEDEX") {
    await updateOrderShipment(orderId, {
      provider: "FEDEX",
      fedex_tracking_number: webhookData.tracking_number,
      fedex_estimated_delivery_date: webhookData.estimated_delivery_date,
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

My issue here is that my app does not recognize additional attributes on the updateOrderShipment method. I'm get errors like `'ups_tracking_number' does not exist in type 'ParcelTracking'`.

Another issue I am anticipating is that I'd like the extension packages to add atributes to the core type - not replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to achieve is an augmented declaration of type aliases. Altough this is possible as described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28078) and [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513652/extend-union-type), it is not as readable as expected.

If the type safety provided by type unions is not absolutely necessary, you can add properties and method to an interface like this:

```js
// package/shipping/index.d.ts
interface ParcelTracking = {
  provider: string;
}

// package/@shipping/ups-provider/index.d.ts
declare module "shipping" {
  interface ParcelTracking {
    ups_tracking_number: string;
  }
}
// package/@shipping/fedex-provider/index.d.ts
declare module "shipping" {
  interface ParcelTracking {
    fedex_tracking_number: string;
    fedex_estimated_delivery_date: string;
  }
}
```

Please note that this solution adds attributes but **does not** prevent things like this

```js
const tracking: ParcelTracking = {
  provider: "UPS",
  fedex_tracking_number: "fedex-1234",
  fedex_estimated_delivery_date: "2029-12-06",
}
```